# How to store coordinates on mongodb for non latitude/longitude fields?

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I'm trying to create 2D space and save coordinates with geojson. I tryied to use 2d index, but when I try to insert and coordinate like 70/50 it tells me that "longitude / latitude is out of bounds".
How can I tell mongodb that this is not the latitude / longitude?

On the official documentation it tells me that "If specifying latitude and longitude coordinates, list the longitude first and then latitude". That  "if" makes me believe that I can store something else, not only latitude and logitude, but I do not see how to do it.

Comment: Did you try to create the index as `"2d"`? Or did you actually create the index as `"2dsphere"`? Clearly the former is the correct format. If you are trying to use GeoJSON, then of course you cannot. You can only validly store without "implying" the longitude and latitude by using a plain array i.e `"location": [50,70]`. The [documentation even says this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#legacy-coordinate-pairs) *"To calculate distances on a Euclidean plane, store your location data as legacy coordinate pairs and use a 2d index"*.  Euclidean plane means "flat" of course.

Comment: The problem with 2d is that I cannot use $geointersects. I neet to be able to check if an area (or point, or line) intersects with another. And even using 2d indexes, I cannot store values above 100, even setting min/max on index creation. And in this case it doesn't respect the min/max when I try to insert  new document